# Looking for Windows 3.11 pdf writer application

Tags: pdf, windows-3.1

I've spent hours on trying to find such app. I need an Acrobat Writer(versions from 1.0 to 3.0) or if better an Acrobat Distiller (versions from 1.0 to 3.0) which can be run in Win16 environment.

I've installed in my Windows 3.11 ghostscript and it can produce postscript files. The same app actually comtains ps2pdf batch file which can be used to make a conversion. But this batch file doesn't work. When I invoke it it says that the file or command not found though it shows the usage string when I invoke it without passing any parameters. The higher versions of ghostscript and gsview require win32s v.130 to be installed. But the only stable version working in Windows 311 is the 1.25b. So I'm kind of stuck...

Doesn't matter what exactly should be used I just **need to be able to produce PDF files inside(only) Windows 3.11**.

Comment: Why you need that? Why in the world someone like to use windows 3.1 to produce PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reliably finding software for that old a Windows variant is not going to be easy I'm afraid.

An alternative that you could try if the machine exists on a network with more modern setups is to install the driver for a postscript printer and have that set to "print to file" (or keep using ghostscript to produce the PDFs, thought the driver approach may be faster). You could then pick up the resulting .ps files over the network and convert them to PDFs using another machine.

Comment: Hi. Thx for the answer. Do you know any postscript printers for windows 3.11? Ghostscript 4.03 prints only 1 page for some reason. Ghostscript 6 I can't install cause it requires "win32s v1.3" and exactly this version of win32s crashes the system. Adding postscript prnters from the control panel and getting their drivers from the Windows311.iso is Ok but it also prints only 1 page.

Comment: If *both* GS and standard Windows printer drivers sending output to a file only print a single page then I would suspect the application to be at fault rather than the printer driver.